# How to make @Html.DisplayFor() use ToString() on object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

PurchaseOrderModel.cs

```
public class PurchaseOrderModel {
    public SupplierModel Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

SupplierModel.cs

```
public class SupplierModel {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return $"{Name} ({Code})";
    }
}
```

PurchseOrdersReport.cshtml

```
@Html.DisplayFor(purchaseOrder => purchaseOrder.Supplier)
```

I would like that the Razor engine calls the `ToString()` method of `Supplier`. But it doesn't, I got the following HTML output instead:

```
<div class="display-label">Code</div>
<div class="display-field">USSCIESTMI</div>
<div class="display-label">Name</div>
<div class="display-field">MY SUPPLIER NAME</div>
```

Comment: `DisplayNameFor()` uses the name of the property or the value of the `[Display(Name = "..")]` if present. Why not just use `@Model.Supplier.ToString()`?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(purchaseOrder => purchaseOrder.Supplier)` will generate HTML markup with type name of `SupplierModel`. If you want `DisplayNameFor` to display formatted string, create a [display template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490904/create-a-template-for-displaynamefor-method-in-asp-net-mvc) instead.

Comment: And I assume you have a typo in your code, and you meant `@Html.DisplayFor()`, not `@Html.DisplayNameFor()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke indeed, I fixed the typo. And yes Model.Supplier.ToString() is what I use, I just wanted to be consistent with the rest of my stsatements, which all use Html.DisplayFor. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found another topic at Stack overflow that outlines the following solution. Please refer [How to show the model's attribute dynamically in mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516230/how-to-show-the-models-attribute-dynamically-in-mvc)

There is a overload for @Html.DisplayFor(...) that takes two args.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(purchaseOrder => purchaseOrder.Supplier, Model.Supplier.ToString())
```

Comment: The 2nd parameter is the name of the `DisplayTemplate` - i.e. the name of a `.cshtml` file. This has nothing to do with OP's issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@(Model.PropertyType.ToString())
```

Or simply

```
@Model.PropertyType
```

instead of `@Html.DisplayFor`